# Server Keeps Dropping Active Connections, But Pings

Tags: 11.04, server

I have a very frustrating problem with a new server I built.

On every machine that SSHes in (or any other connection), the connection gets dropped randomly between immediately, and 30 minutes into the session, while the user is actively using the system remotely (typing, etc). Before, during and after the disconnection, the system responds to pings regularly (0% packet loss).

It takes about 5-10 minutes before I can make a connection again.

I have tried restarting SSH, apache, etc on the server and rebooting the server. I even removed and reinstalled these services and this still happens. I have disabled iptables, ufw and removed firestarter.

What might be causing these random disconnects?

Comment: Could it be a (broken / misconfigured) router between your machines which is dropping connections?

Comment: Perhaps, but it is only occurring with this one server. I have others that respond correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced symptoms similar to this before.  Not certain of why you cannot reconnect until after 5-10 minutes.  I'll guess and say it is a firewall configuration between you and the Ubuntu box allowing only so many orphaned connections until a specific time threshold expires.  I've seen this in the Cisco ASAs and OpenBSD's PF.

On any *nix box I admin, I enter the following into /etc/ssh/ssh_config to keep my connections alive

```
ServerAliveInterval 180
```

FYI...this is entered on the client and not the server.  Your mileage my vary so you might have to raise or lower this value.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This happens on ALL incoming connections, not just SSH.

Comment: You need to check the following then:Duplicate IP, Firewall Config, Interface flapping

Comment: There were a few things. First, the IP was conflicting. Even though I configured the trouble IP with a different MAC in the router, neither the router nor the other machine would give up the IP address. In my testing, I swapped cables. Unfortunately, that cable had a bad crimp and damaged a pin on the NICs. I was able to bend it back and it works, but I will need to buy another card for the future. This was causing NO DHCPOFFERS error message.